# sudo npm i npm or sudo npm install npm@latest -g throws an error of EACCES:permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm v 5.6 and I installed node version 10.1 so the current npm doesn't support node version while updating npm I am getting EACCES permission denied error. I tried removing npm directory and updating via several command the npm version is stuck at 5.6. Help!!
Using Ubuntu v16.04 LTS.
I tried installing different nodejs version too but it also doesnt change npm version(npm v5.6).

[visit here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q4mS.png)

Comment: Well you need root privilieges to globally update npm. Assuming you're on a UNIX-like machine `sudo npm i npm`

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: I did that too the npm doesn't change the version always remain the same

Comment: Would you be open to using a version manager? It would mean that you could install multiple versions of Node and switch between them at will. If so, I could write an answer explaining how to do that. Also, don't install anything from npm using sudo. It's a security risk and leads to permissions errors, as you have seen.

Comment: Yes sure anything that works!

Comment: Answer added. Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a version manager (such as [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)) to install multiple versions of Node.js and switch between them at will.

First off, make sure you have `git` and the `build-essential` package installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
```

Then install nvm with cURL (run this command in your terminal):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

This will clone the nvm repository to `~/.nvm` and will make the required changes to your bash profile, so that nvm is available from anywhere in your terminal.

Reload your bash profile:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and verify the install by typing:

```
command -v nvm
```

which should output 'nvm' if the installation was successful.

(if this doesn't work, just close, then reopen your terminal)

And that’s it, nvm is installed and ready to be used.

---

Now, to download, compile, and install the latest release of Node, run the following from your terminal:

```
nvm install node
```

And then in any *new shell* just use the installed version:

```
nvm use node
```

Finally, verify the correct version is being used:

```
node -v
=> 10.5.0
```

There's a lot more to using nvm, such as installing multiple Node versions.

You can read more about that here: https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

HTH